# Point of incrementing count?

Tags: python-3.x

I am taking a course in Python and it is Python 3.4. I am confused as to the reasoning behind what incrementing a code does.

Example:

```
while True:
    print count
    count += 1
    if count >= 10:
        break
```

What is the point of the incrementing and count of += 1?

Comment: I tried fixing your indentation. In future, please highlight your code and hit Ctrl+K or use the `{}` icon in the editing toolbar to make sure your code is properly formatted.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Are you asking why someone would add 1 to a variable? If so, it's because they need it to be 1 higher.

Comment: I'm not sure we're speaking the same language.  What distinction are you drawing between "incrementing" and "count of += 1"?  What exactly are you asking?

Comment: The point of this toy example is to teach two things: 1. augmented assignment to increment, which is occasionally needed in spite of the availability of `for i in range(n):`; `while True:` with a `break` to implement an 'until condition' loop, which is also occasionally needed.

Answer (score 0):

`count` will be incremented by `1`, so if `count` is `5` it'll be `6` after `count += 1`.

This way, the while loop that at first looks like an infinite loop will be broken out of after 10 loops because `if count >= 10` will be `true`.

This will print out something like : `0123456789` if `count` starts at `0`

Comment: Someone is sniping them downvotes. Add a comment if you're going to downvote, please.

Comment: This isn't a useful answer. There isn't a useful answer to this question the way it is right now.

Comment: @MorganThrapp The question specifically is "why would you increment it?" And I answered that question to the best of my knowing. The question itself might not be that good but saying the answer is not useful is incorrect when it comes to the question at hand.

Comment: It doesn't answer "why". To be fair, the question is incredibly vague. Why is the counter being incremented instead of using a for loop? or `print(list(range(10))`? All this does is say that `c+=1` increments `c` by one.

Comment: @MorganThrapp And it answers why, because the break has a condition that's used in combination with this incremeting. I disagree.